# What is causing this error when using flatMap?

Tags: scala

This code :

```
1 until 3 flatMap (x => x + 1)
```

causes this error in worksheet :

```
Multiple markers at this line
- type mismatch;  found   : Int(1)  required: String
- type mismatch;  found   : Int(1)  required: String
- type mismatch;  found   : x.type (with underlying type Int)  required: ?{def +(x$1: ? >: Int(1)): ?} Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:  both method int2long in object Int of type (x: Int)Long  and method int2float in object Int of type (x: Int)Float  are possible conversion functions from x.type to ?{def +(x$1: ? >: Int(1)): ?}
- type mismatch;  found   : x.type (with underlying type Int)  required: ?{def +(x$1: ? >: Int(1)): ?} Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:  both method int2long in object Int of type (x: Int)Long  and method int2float in object Int of type (x: Int)Float  are possible conversion functions from x.type to ?{def +(x$1: ? >: Int(1)): ?}
```

This code behaves as expected : `1 until 3 flatMap (x => x + 1)`

Should all collections that are applicable to `map` also be applicable to `flatMap` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that when you say:

This code behaves as expected : `1 until 3 flatMap (x => x + 1)`

You meant to write `1 until 3 map (x => x + 1)`

The version with `map` works because `map` takes a function from `A => B`, and returns a list of `B` (that is, a `List[B]`).

The version with `flatMap` does not work because `flatMap` requires a function from `A => List[B]` and then returns a `List[B]`.  (More precisely, it's a `GenTraversableOnce[B]` but you can treat it like a List in this situation)  The function you are trying to apply to flatMap does not return a List, so it doesn't work for what you are trying to do.

From that error message, it's hard to see this.  In general, I think you'll get clearer error messages on statements like this if you don't go crazy trying to remove all the parentheses from your statements.

Answer (score 1):

The flatMap expects result of the function to be traversable

```
def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): IndexedSeq[B]
```

Not a simple type ( x + 1 )
To join later all of the results into single sequence.

Working example:

```
scala> def f: (Int => List[Int]) = { x => List(x + 1) }
f: Int => List[Int]

scala> 1 until 3 flatMap ( f )
res6: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea of flatMap is that the function you pass has a list (or a "GenTraversableOnce", I'll just call it list, informally) as a result, so map would result in a list of lists. flatMap flattens that to one list.

Or in other words, I think the equivalent of your map example would be
1 until 3 flatMap (x => List(x + 1))